# Python save images in three channels and float type (to avoid losing precision)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a picture with pixels in `float32` type. I want to retain float type in my image in deep learning tasks.

However, from what I know PIL image save function only supports `uint8` data type, but I don't want to convert my `float32` data to `uint8` as this would lose precision.

Thus, are there any alternatives?

My image has 3 channels and I want to save in jpg format files.

**Note: I do have to use use what i've described, because of the restriction of the deep learning task I'm doing.**

Comment: You first need to decide on a file format, which file format that supports floats do you want to use?

Comment: Note that JPEG does not have any floating point formats.

Comment: If you are not going to have a manual look at your files then just save them using `np.save()`.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I can't do that, because in tensorflow I need to use its load_images_from_directory function, which can only identify image files...

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I would use whatever format that supports three channels and float type.

Comment: The GEGL library - it preserves precision, and do have formats that can preserve then (at least TIFF) - although you won't find much informatiopn on how to use it with Python at this moment, it will work through gobject introspection.

Comment: @Walker No, the use of load_images_from_directory is not mandatory, and also this function does not support any format for floating point images.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Oh okay, thanks for reminding me thou. I don't know load_images_from_directory don't support any image formats with floating point. I know this is not mandatory, it would just be more convenient for me to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 considerations - firstly, the file formats and secondly, library support of those formats. So, regarding file formats, the following do not support float data:

- JPEG
- PNG
- GIF
- BMP
- TGA

The following formats DO support floating point data:

- TIFF supports floating point data as 32 or 64-bit
- [PFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#32-bit_extensions) supports 32-bit floats and you can very easily read/write to that yourself
- JPEG XR and JPEG XL also support floats - thanks to @cgohlke
- EXR format may also work

So you are more-or-less stuck with TIFF or PFM if you want to be fairly main-stream. Now let's look at support for those two formats in some packages:

- PIL itself does not support 3-channel floats at all
- OpenCV supports 32 and 64-bit floats and can read and write TIFF (and PFM IIRC)
- [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) supports 32 and 64-bit floats and can read and write TIFF (and probably PFM IIRC)
- [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) supports 32 and 64-bit floats
- [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) supports floats

---

Note that Numpy can read/write floats in its own format, but those are not readily viewable by anything other than Numpy.

Likewise OpenCV can probably store floats in its `FileStorage` format, but that too is not viewable by any regular image viewers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For PNG type however, as I tried, it supports float type, the only issue with it is when importing, by default there would be four channels, in which I don't want. But your answer is nearly perfect and definitely deserves many upvotes!!

Comment: No, PNG doesn't support more than 16-bits per channel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

Comment: Got u, so I guess float16 type suffices with this, in which I'm also okay with that. Thank you so much for that :)

Comment: No, the 16-bit format is unsigned integer, not float.

Comment: That's strange, I've just tested my code, I successfully exported my image array to **png** using `plt.imsave()` and I imported with `plt.imread()`, as a result, the `float32` type is retained. It's only that it has 4 channels. And whatever float datatype I used when exporting, the imported datatype is float32.

Comment: That seems to be `matplotlib` rather than PIL. I tried saving a 48x64x3 array of floats with it as a PNG. It didn't return any errors, but it actually wrote a PNG with colortype=6 (i.e. RGBA) and a bit-depth=8 which is wrong on several levels.

Comment: FWIW, JPEG XR and JPEG XL also support 32-bit float.